# Does "Kehilat Bethlehem" community believe that the Law of Moses are the commandments Jesus is referring to in John 14:15?

Tags: gospel-of-john, mosaic-law, messianic-judaism

Does [Kehilat Bethlehem](https://kehilatbethlechem.com/about-us/about-kehilat-bethlehem/) community believe that the Law of Moses are the commandments Jesus is referring to in John 14:15?

> John 14:15: If you love Me, you will keep **My commandments**.

And do they believe circumcision is or keeping any part of the Law of Moses is essential to be engrafted the household of Israel (called the commonwealth of Israel) to be part of the bride of Jesus?

They state that

> We believe that salvation is by grace through faith as revealed in the Torah.

and give emphasis to the Law in the first five books of the Bible and are keen to follow the Jewish traditions which are unusual to both Catholics and Protestants.

Answer (score 3):

EDIT : The question has been edited since I answered. This answer contains general information about Kehilat Bethlechem.

The questions one would first ask of the website are the very questions which the website does not discuss.

Notably, I could find no place in which they confess that Jesus is the Christ, the Son of God. They mention Jesus. Separately, they mention God, Father, Son and Holy Spirit. They mention Messiah. But they never actually say (that I can find) that Jesus of Nazareth is the Messiah, the Christ, the Son of God.

Presumably, one has to watch many hours of videos to actually find out information which ought to be on its front page, regarding law, circumcision, faith and works.

---

The link you provide has extensive information but most is in video form. The website has a large library of videos which form a methodical form of indoctrination.

The website invites donations and the donations are payable to :

> Kehilat Bethlechem

Some written material is available :

> Our service consists of Jewish liturgy in Hebrew and English, modern Messianic Jewish praise and worship music followed by the message. We also have a Torah service on the first Shabbat of every month. Once the service is over, we meet over a light snack for building community and fellowship.

> everyone is not only respected, but encouraged to walk in the faith of Yeshua, our Messiah.

> We partner globally with Ahavat Ammi Ministries in United States on all their educational programs.

> Kosher Pastor is a program that explores the Jewish Roots of Christian faith by connecting the life of Jesus in its context

> Joseph John is the President/ Senior Pastor of Kehilat Bethlechem, a Messianic congregation in Hyderabad, India. He was an Assemblies of G-d pastor when he had a **supernatural encounter with the Lord while reading the Book of Romans.**

> he “saw” that the **non-Jewish believers in Yeshua were engrafted into Israel**!

> Kehilat Bethlechem gathers on Shabbat and is committed to discipleship and training of workers **to build the Kingdom of G-d by revealing the true identity of the Jewish Messiah and His Kingdom.**

This organisation is affiliated to and is part of the IAMCS -the Messianic Jewish Alliance of America.

> The IAMCS is a subsidiary of the Messianic Jewish Alliance of America (MJAA). The MJAA, founded in 1915, is the largest association of Messianic Jews and non-Jewish believers in Yeshua (Jesus) in the world. Its purpose is threefold:

> • To testify to the large and growing number of Jewish people who believe that Yeshua (Hebrew for Jesus) is the promised Jewish Messiah and Savior of the world;

> • **To bring together Jews and non-Jews who have a shared vision for Jewish revival; and**

> • Most importantly, to introduce our Jewish brothers and sisters to the Jewish Messiah Yeshua.

The IAMCS has a page in which they state some of their beliefs. In particular there is reference to the Father, the Son and the Holy Spirit :

[See IAMCS Belief](https://iamcs.org/about-us/belief)